# Error in C++ : redefinition of class constructor using templates

Tags: c++, list, templates

Anybody know how I can fix these errors?
i have been looking at it for a while and just cannot figure out what to do.

Error:

```
indexList.cpp:18: error: redefinition of `indexList<T>::indexList()'
indexList.cpp:18: error: `indexList<T>::indexList()' previously declared here
indexList.cpp:30: error: redefinition of `bool indexList<T>::append(T)'
indexList.cpp:30: error: `bool indexList<T>::append(T)' previously declared here
```

cpp file:

```
//
//
//
//
//
//
#include "indexList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//constuctor
//Descriptions: Initializes numberOfElement to 0
//              Initializes maxSize to 100
//Parameters:   none
//Return:       none
template <class T>
indexList<T>::indexList()
{
  numberOfElements = 0;
  maxSize = 100;
}


//Name: append
//Purpose: Adds element to the end of the list. If array is full, returns false
//Paramters: value - thing to append
//Return: true if append succeeds, false otherwise
template <class T>
bool indexList<T>::append(T value)
{
  if (maxSize > numberOfElements)
    {
      list[numberOfElements] = value;
      numberOfElements ++;
      return true;
    }
  else
    return false;
}
```

I didn't put all the the cpp file because the rest of the errors are similar to the ones above, and it is quite long

header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#ifndef INDEXLIST_H
#define INDEXLIST_H

template <class T>
class indexList
{
 public:
 indexList();

 bool append(T value);

 bool insert(int indx, T value);

 bool replace(int indx, T newValue);

 bool retrieve(int indx, T &value) const;

 bool remove(int indx);

 void sort();

 int search(T value) const;

private:
 T list[100];
 int numberOfElements;
 int maxSize;
};


template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &outStream, const indexList<T> &lst);

#include "indexList.cpp"

#endif
```

I did put the entire header

Comment: Does anything other than `indexList.h` include the file `indexList.cpp`?

Comment: there is a indexListApp.cpp but it only has a #include "indexList.h"

Comment: Do you need to `#include "indexList.h"` in indexList.cpp?

Comment: indexList.cpp line 18 and 30 are which lines? I tried to count but cannot match the lines...

Comment: i have added comments to make up for the part i omitted to line it up again

Answer (score 3):

Each of your two files tries to include the other, which can cause the preprocessor to output some repeated code.

Take the `#include "indexList.h"` out of the file `indexList.cpp`.

Also, your build process should not attempt to compile `indexList.cpp` into an object file.

Another way to arrange things would be to just put all the contents you currently have in `indexList.cpp` near the end of `indexList.h`, and there would be no `indexList.cpp` file at all.

Comment: so i took the #include "indexList.h" out of the cpp but I still get the same errors.

Comment: I would also make the recommendation of renaming `indexList.cpp` to `indexList.hpp` for clarity, it is a convention I've seen somewhere and I like it. It ensures that you don't accidentally add the `.hpp` to your makefile. +1

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is ok, but you must realise that the .cpp file should not itself be compiled into an object - instead, just include the .h file from your application code:

```
// main.cc

#include "indexList.h"

int main()
{
    indexList<int> il;
}

c++ -o main main.cc
```

I'd bet it's because you've tried to do a `c++ -c indexList.cpp` or `c++ indexList.cpp` that you get the errors (or perhaps your make tool is trying that automatically for all .cpp files in your source code directories - you could try renaming indexList.cpp to indexList.inl or .inc or whatever - remember to change the name in indexList.h too - to see if that fixes the problem), as in that situation the definitions are seen twice: once as the compile includes indexList.h, and again as it finishes compiling indexList.cpp.

There's no need to include indexList.h from within the .cpp anyway - that makes it look as if the indexList.cpp is designed for separate compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Put any of your templated methods in an `indexList.inl` file, and include that from your header. Don't include the header from this file.

Put any other methods in your `indexList.cpp` file. Include the header from this file.